# How to test Https connections locally Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate, bitnami

I think I may have a misconception

I am trying to include https in my local settings so that I dont have to keep changing every link in my application from http to https every time i upload it to my web host. I had downloaded bitnami for my local developement and im using apache. How can I use https in local environment? Do I not understand some fundamental? I keep hearing something about self-signed certificates. Does this apply to me?

Hope this is the right place for the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami developer here

About the first question, you can force https redirection for your application adding the following in the `bitnami.conf` (/installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf) file inside the default  directive (in the example below using port 80):

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
...
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Please note that after modifying the Apache configuration files, you will need to restart  Apache to apply the changes.

Regarding the self-signed certificates, you can follow these steps:

First create your private key (if you haven't created it already):

`/installdir/common/bin/openssl genrsa -out /installdir/apache2/conf/server.key 2048`

Later, the certificate request is created like this:

`/installdir/common/bin/openssl req -new -key /installdir/apache2/conf/server.key -out /installdir/apache2/conf/cert.csr`

While the certificate authority checks your request, you can create a temporary self-signed certificate:

`/installdir/common/bin/openssl x509 -in /installdir/apache2/conf/cert.csr -out /installdir/apache2/conf/server.crt -req -signkey /installdir/apache2/conf/server.key -days 365`

You can find more information about this in our wiki:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_create_a_SSL_certificate.3f